# Keeping part of a string in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, regex

I have a dataframe with the following column

```
city <- c("Sydney NSW", "Newcastle NSW", "Liverpool NSW", "Broken Hill NSW")
```

I want to maintain everything prior to `NSW` (space included). What Regex expression can be used in R for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strsplit()`.

If you want to remove the space between the two words (along with 'NSW'):

`city_clean <- unlist(c(strsplit(city, " NSW")))`

Output: `[1] "Sydney"      "Newcastle"   "Liverpool"   "Broken Hill"`

It wasn't clear to me whether you wanted to keep the space or not. If you want to *keep* the trailing space after the city name

`city_clean <- unlist(c(strsplit(city, "NSW")))`

Output: `[1] "Sydney "      "Newcastle "   "Liverpool "   "Broken Hill "`

If you prefer to use regex, here's another solution:

`city_clean <- gsub(" NSW", "", city)`

Output: `[1] "Sydney"      "Newcastle"   "Liverpool"   "Broken Hill"`

Comment: Worked perfectly :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could use

```
gsub("NSW$", "", city)
```

This function is vectorized and performs the replacement in all elements of the vector.

With the tidyverse package `stringr` you could use the vectorized function `str_replace`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(city, "NSW$", "")
```

Here the order of arguments is more natural, in my opinion.

`stringr` depends on `stringi`. If you have to install these packages first, it will take a while because R will compile a lot of helper C/C++ code during installation.